# Mysql error on INSERT Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql

Hi I'm having an error using MySQL in Java. I keep getting this unknown column error everytime I try to insert into my table (when I run "testOne" below).

```
public static void sendMessage(String username, String recipientName, String message, String title) {                
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");                
    Date date = new Date();                
    String stringDate = dateFormat.format(date);                
    String query = "INSERT INTO messages" + " (fromUser, toUser, message, title, dateCreated) VALUES ('" + 
    username + "', '" + recipientName + "', '" + message + "', '" + title + "', '" + stringDate + "')";                                   
    DBConnection.getInstance().executeQuery(query);                
}

public void testOne(){
    Message.sendMessage("user1", "user2", "hows it going", "hi");
}

CREATE TABLE messages (
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fromUser varchar(255),
    toUser varchar(255), 
    mType int,
    message TEXT,
    title TEXT,
    dateCreated varchar(255),
    seen TINYINT(1),
    quizID int,
    PRIMARY KEY(pID)
  );

public ResultSet executeQuery(String query){
    ResultSet rs= null;
    try {
        java.sql.Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        // this is the trick -- you need to pass different SQL to different methods
        if (query.startsWith("SELECT")) {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        } else if (query.startsWith("UPDATE") || query.startsWith("INSERT")
                || query.startsWith("DELETE")) {
            stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        } else {
            stmt.execute(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return rs;
}

public static DBConnection getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new DBConnection(DBConnection.rootDirectory);
    return instance;
}
```

But I get this error everytime I run the test- Unknown column 'message' in 'field list'
Please help!!!

Comment: When I print out the query, it looks like this:                  INSERT INTO messages (fromUser, toUser, message, title, dateCreated) VALUES ('user1', 'user2', 'hows it going', 'hi', '2013:11:28 13:39:32')

Comment: What if the message contains a single quote? Learn about prepared statements.

Comment: Please help I just want to insert into my table. The message won't contain any quotes.

Comment: You're probably not inserting into the right database. Or the table doesn't have the columns you think it has. And I repeat, learn about prepared statements. This code is not only not robust, but it's also inefficient and dangerous, opening your code to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: But the table contains a message column, and I am able to insert "fromUser" and "toUser"

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statement is incorrect.  The column `pID`, mentioned in the `PRIMARY KEY` clause, does not exist.

Comment: Thanks I fixed that but I still get the same error. I changed "pID" to "id"

Comment: What does your `DBConnection.getInstance()` method return?  How is its `executeQuery` method defined?  `DBConnection.getInstance()` cannot return a `java.sql.Connection` object, as that has no `executeQuery` method, and I doubt it returns a `java.sql.Statement`, as you can't use `Statement.executeQuery` to execute an `INSERT` statement.  (`INSERT` statements are not queries.)

Comment: I added executeQuery to the code above. Would really appreciate your help thanks

Comment: getInstance returns a Connection, I added that above too

Comment: Can you run the query using the mysql console/workbench?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this.  Your code works; I can insert into that table.  All I can say to you is to check which MySQL database you are connecting to, and check that this database contains a `message` column.

Comment: @Taylor, do you mean run through command line?

Comment: @user2057841 yes or the workbench.

Comment: My take is the you need to specify values for _all_ columns. You have excluded some columns, and that the problem. Put `NULL` for columns you have no data.

Answer (score 0):

Which column are you getting the error? I was facing similar problem. I placed space before and after "," in values String and it worked out well. In your case try adding space before Comma.